# How can I stop flexslider slideshow from crashing on iPad due to too many photos?

Tags: jquery, ipad, memory, slideshow, flexslider

I have an issue with Flexslider, on iPad it seems to crash due to too many images, because if I lessen the number of images it runs fine. You can see the slideshow at: http://lestroisverres.ch/galerie/

Is there anything I can do fix this with the ipad's memory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 'SOLUTION' seems to be not abusing css3 'transform'. In my case i was using flexslider with custom extra css navigation elements with opacity and hover animations like the < > flexslider arrows. This extra elements where causing too much work for the retina iPad gpu (apple bad design?) so i set some elements static, always visible plus no opacity, no animation,. even simplified removing some elements. This prevented ipad crashing much less than before. Still not 100% solved, but as I said, the problem seems to be a weak graphics card for a retina display like the iPad uses.

Also it seems to be some of the CSS involved that iOs doesn't like...

```
    .flexslider .slides > li {
        display: none;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
```

Check this out:
https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/727

The problem seems to be an incorrect implementation of the CSS3 transform property in iPad and mobile retina devices/bad apple hardware design.

This css property seems to consume lot of memory:
[iOS Safari runs out of memory with "-webkit-transform"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824060/ios-safari-runs-out-of-memory-with-webkit-transform)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.